# Not able to install digits from Fabric plugin in android app

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter-fabric

If I tried to install digit from fabric plugin in eclipse and it shows progressbar as shown in the screenshot below.It never succeeds.

[image]

Comment: Did you run your app?

Comment: it is most probably installed.You just need to run your app now so that it may check that is it properly configured or not.

Comment: TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());  give error TwitterAuthConfig cannot be resolved to a 
  type in oncreate.So unable to run the app.

Comment: @Tushar189 Have you got it working? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Not working I left it @SSS

Comment: @Tushar189 Ok. So sad :(